# How to map recipes with ingredients using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

I have following RecipeModel, IngredientModel and RecipePartModel classes which represent the DTO classes for the frontend user:

```
public class RecipeModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RecipePartModel> RecipeParts { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RecipePartModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IngredientModel Ingredient { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my entity classes:

```
public class Recipe : BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<RecipePart> RecipeParts { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient : BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<RecipePart> RecipeParts { get; set; }
}

public class RecipePart : BaseEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My question is - how can I map the Recipe to RecipeModel using AutoMapper? I tried something like this but I assume it is bad, because it just join all the RecipeParts for the whole database, am I correct?

```
public class DomainProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientModel>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Recipe, RecipeModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.RecipeParts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecipeParts));
    }
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat sorry for my choise and thanks for tips. I will try my best next time.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about how to use AutoMapper to map a type to another type, there are many ways of doing this. Documentation is here: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html.

I wrote a console app and got it working in the quickest way I know possible using your code. When I debug this, and check inside recipeModel, it references a list of RecipePartModels with a single RecipePartModel. Inside that RecipePartModel, it references an IngredientModel.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var profile = new DomainProfile();

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(profile));

        var recipe = new Recipe
        {
            RecipeParts = new List<RecipePart>
            {
                new RecipePart()
                {
                    Ingredient = new Ingredient()
                }
            }
        };

        var recipeModel = Mapper.Map<Recipe, RecipeModel>(recipe);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

To answer your concern about getting all recipes from the database, if you're using Entity Framework, it depends on if you have lazy loading turned on. Lazy loading ensures that, when you get a recipe from the database, the recipe parts will not be loaded. They will only be loaded when you access the recipe part directly later on in the program flow. Lazy loading is turned on by default so this is the default behaviour. If you turn it off, you've enabled eager loading which loads all recipe parts and in turn their ingredient.

This might help: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer. Indeed this mapping which I wrote was really ok

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad about this mapping. In fact you don't even need the ForMember call as this is the default convention. The mapping will simply convert each element in the entity child collection to a corresponding model object.

Of course, whether you load your entities in an efficient manner is another matter. If you load a large amount of Recipe entities, and lazy load the RecipeParts collections for each, you will have a major "SELECT N+1" problem. But this is not the fault of AutoMapper.

Comment: Indeed! It was a paradox that I had to write this question to realize that everything was ok with this mapping :D